# @keydown doesnt trigger method in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have defined two methods as below. But the problem I am facing is that the @keydown doesn't trigger the method. I switched the methods, that is I put updateLength method on @keyup then it works. How can I make the both the methods works one on keyup and other on keydown.

```
<v-flex xs12 sm8>
    <div class="form-group">
        <v-text-field
        v-model='money.number'
        maxlength='22'
        name="number"
        @keydown="updateLength"
        @keyup="checkLength"
        required>
        </v-text-field>
    </div>
</v-flex>


<script>
export default {
 data() {
  return {
   money: {
      number: ''
   }
  }
 },
 methods: {
   checkLength: function(event) {
        console.log("UPWARDS")
      },
   updateLength: function(event) {
        console.log("DOWNWARDS")
      }
 }    
</script>
```

Comment: Works fine in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/RwPoZjy?editors=1011). Can you provide a repro in Codepen?

Answer (score 2):

```
@keyup.native="checkNumber"
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You bound the text field to the model number, however it is not defined.
Uncaught errors break the event loop.

Also, you should wrap all the code inside script in export default wrapper.

Comment: I have posted the question in the correct format. This is how I have it.

Comment: It works fine for me, can you post an exact replica of your code on codepen for us to see?